# Saving and retrieving data from core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, ios4

I have a program where I save an int value as follows:

```
client.oldId = [clientDict objectForKey:@"oldId"];
```

At this point when debugging the value that is saved "supposely" is 31.

When I attempt to retrieve this item using the context, and i retrieve it as follows:

```
 int oldId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:client.oldId];
```

It becomes 174806944, why could this happen?, there are no summation operations or anything like that for this item and right before it saves to the context it is 31.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set your variable to 0 before you set it

```
int oldId = 0
oldid = [NSNumber numberWithInt:client.oldId];
```

sometimes you can get garbage in a memory location that can cause this.

**Updated Answer:** Though technically sometimes I have found that if you dont clear out the integer I get the same thing. In this case he was setting an `int` to an `NSNumber`. The correct way was to take the NSNumber and get its `integerValue` like this:

```
[client.oldId intValue]
```

Comment: Hello thank you, i tried this still the same issue. Its just weird

Comment: If what I am seeing `client.oldId` is an NSNumber (i assume)... why not do it this way `oldId = [client.oldId intValue]`

Comment: will try these suggestions and get back in a few minutes thanks :)

Comment: @logixologist: You should update your answer with the correct code using `intValue`. (And setting oldId to zero before assigning a value to it does not make much sense.)